# How to replace all matching integer characters with asterisks

Tags: java

I am fairly new to java and I need some help with my code.

I am trying to replace all characters equal to the first character of the input (except the first character) with an asterisk(*).

Example:

-input: 1231231231

-output: 123*23*23*

This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  while(in.hasNextInt())
  {
      int inputLine = in.nextInt();
      System.out.println(processLine(inputLine));
  } 
  }

 public static long processLine(int inputLine) {

  String convert = Integer.toString(inputLine);
  String firstDigit = convert.substring(0,1);
  String filter = convert.replaceAll(firstDigit,"*");
  long result = Long.parseLong(filter);
  return result;

 }
 }
```

but it returns a error saying:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "*23*23"

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: You can't put asterisks in the string and then say `parseLong` as what you have at that point is no longer a `long`. Probably `processLine` should return a `String`, not a `long`.

Comment: Also, replaceAll is for replacing substrings matching a regexp. You want to replace a character (or a literal substring). Use replace(). Read the javadoc.

Comment: So is there any other way to replace integer characters other than converting them to strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take the `substring` of everything *after* the first character before you call `replaceAll`. For example,

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while (in.hasNextInt()) {
    int inputLine = in.nextInt();
    String v = Integer.toString(inputLine), f = v.substring(0, 1);
    System.out.println(f + v.substring(1).replaceAll(f, "*"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the following regular expression to match for replacement:

```
(?<!^)1
```

Explanation:
`(?<!^)`: if the character is not at the beginning of the line. (i.e. Negative Lookback for beginning of line)

`1`: match on 1.

Full call for your replacement:

```
public static String processLine(int inputLine) {

    String convert = Integer.toString(inputLine);
    return inputLine.replaceAll("(?<!^)1", "*");
}
```